# Sencha Touch 2 - Main Width?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

my english is bad and why I write short and direct :o)

**my view :**

```
Ext.define('Anteile.view.Main', {
extend      : 'Ext.Container',
xtype       : 'xmain',
maxWidth    :800,
maxHeight   :400,
config      : {
    layout      : 'fit',
    id          :'Main',
    fullscreen  : true,
    items       : [
        { xtype : 'xNavigationBar' },
        { xtype : 'xSidebar' },
        { xtype : 'xMainContainerView', flex : 1 }
    ]
}
} );
```

**my controller :**

```
Ext.define('Anteile.controller.SlideNavigation', {
extend  : 'Ext.app.Controller',
config  : {
    refs:
    {
    // xMain
    xMainContainer  :'xmain',
    idMainContainer :'xmain[id=Main]',
    },
},

init: function() {
    this.callParent();
    this.initContainer();

},

initContainer: function() {
    this.fConsole('this.x: '+this.getXMainContainer().getWidth());
    this.fConsole('this.id: '+this.getIdMainContainer().getWidth());
}

... ...
```

**concole output from initContainer :**

> this.x: null
>
> this.id: null

why is **x and id** NULL instead of 800

Greetings
Volker

Answer (score 0):

I think you are new in Sencha. Well `maxWidth` and `maxHeight`  are the config properties of `container` so you need to include them within config,like this:-

```
Ext.define('Anteile.view.Main', {
extend      : 'Ext.Container',
xtype       : 'xmain',

config      : {
     maxWidth    :800,
     maxHeight   :400,
     layout      : 'fit',
     fullscreen  : true,
     items       : [
        { xtype : 'xNavigationBar' },
        { xtype : 'xSidebar' },
        { xtype : 'xMainContainerView', flex : 1 }
    ]
}
} );
```

Also in the controller if you want to get a reference of a view you will need the `name` property and not `id`. Like this:-

```
View:-

    items: [{
      name: 'test',
      html: 'Test container'

    }]

Controller:-

refs:
    {
   xmain: "xmain",
   testContainer: 'container[name="test"]'
    }
```

**EDIT**

To get the max-width:

```
this.getXMain().getMaxWidth();
```

Answer (score 0):

yes that's true I'm new.

Have it changed now and still NULL

**view**

```
Ext.define('Anteile.view.Main', {
extend      : 'Ext.Container',
xtype       : 'xmain',

config      : {
     maxWidth    :800,
     maxHeight   :400,
     name        :'Main',
     layout      : 'fit',
     fullscreen  : true,
     items       : [
        { xtype : 'xNavigationBar' },
        { xtype : 'xSidebar' },
        { xtype : 'xMainContainerView', flex : 1 }
    ]
}
} );
```

**contoller**

```
Ext.define('Anteile.controller.SlideNavigation', {
extend  : 'Ext.app.Controller',
config  : {
    refs:
    {
    // xMain
    xMainContainer  :'xmain',
    idMainContainer :'xmain[name=Main]', // > idMainContainer :'xmain[name="Main"]' <neither
    },
},

init: function() {
    this.callParent();
    this.initContainer();

},

initContainer: function() {
    this.fConsole('this.x: '+this.getXMainContainer().getWidth());
    this.fConsole('this.id: '+this.getIdMainContainer().getWidth());
}
```

Comment: Since you are setting property as "maxWidth", so you will get the max width as view.getMaxWidth() and if you set the config property as "width" then you will get the width as view.getWidth().

Comment: this.getXMain().getMaxWidth() = 800
this.getXMain().getWidth() = null :o(

Comment: As I said earlier, if you set as `config:{width: 800}`, then your this.getXMain().getWidth() = 800 otherwise null.

Comment: xmain is flexible wide, I want to query. whether xmain less than <800